# MongoDB Error with C#

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have seen the Quickstart Windows and downloaded **mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.4.zip** and this   error appears when I run mongo.exe:

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84   
exception: connect failed
```

What should I do? Do I need to download something else?

Comment: You started the Mongo shell client. Do you also have a server (mongod) running?

Answer (score 1):

`mongo.exe` is the *Mongo Shell*, which will attempt to connect to the server at `localhost:27017` unless you explicitly specify another server and port.

The one you're after is `mongod.exe` (notice the 'd'?), which is the *MongoDB Server*.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you did not start your Mongo DB server.