# error with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I wrote these two commads on the cmd

```
**C:\> cd \my_mongo_dir\bin C:\my_mongo_dir\bin mongod**
```

then I opened the mongo.exe after downloading & unziping mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.4.zip
but also I found the this  error !!:

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84  
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: This is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343067/mongodb-error-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like mongod is not running. It should by default start on port 27017.

Answer (score 0):

Do The following things

1. create a folder data and in that db folder i.e., **drive:\data\db** ex **c:\data\db**
2. First we need to start the server with the command mongod.exe avial in your bin folder like **drive:\mongodb-win32-i386-2.4.6\bin\mongod.exe**
   ex 
   **c:\mongodb-win32-i386-2.4.6\bin\mongod.exe**
3. Run the mongo.exe avail in the bin folder like C:\mongodb-win32-i386-2.4.6\bin\mongo.exe

> **Know How to stop the mongod.exe**

from the client we need to issue these commands

- **use admin**
- **db.shutdownServer()** 
  then automatically mongod will shut and you need to quit from client with exit command
  HAVE A NICE DAY WITH MONGO